# Convert a multiline QString into a one line QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have something like this:

```
void ReadFileAndConvert ()
{
    QFile File (Directory + "/here/we/go");

    if(File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream Stream (&File);
        QString Text;

        do
        {
            Text = Stream.readLine();
            Text = Text.simplified();
            // Here I want to convert the multiline QString Text into a oneline QString

// ...
}
```

The QString Text consists of a multiline Text that I need to convert into a online Text/QString. How can I achieve this? greetings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your text into a `QStringList`, and use `QStringList::join()`, e.g.

```
QStringList doc;
[...]
Text = Stream.readLine();
Text = Text.simplified();
doc << Text;
[...]
QString final = doc.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`readAll`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html#readAll) function of `QTextStream` in order to get a string containing all your text and then use the [`replace`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#replace-8) function of `QString` in order to remove new lines:

```
QString oneLineText = Stream.readAll().replace("\n"," ").simplified();
```

If you have a large file it is better to use the `readLine` function.