# Qt Opposite method of QString::split()

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, qt4, pyqt

Is there any function that do the opposite job of **QString::split()** . I mean I have an array or **List** and I'd like to add them with a **QString glue**.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666851/594137) shows usage of `QStringList::join()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`QStringList::join`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html#join)

Answer (score 2):

There is QStringList::join, i think that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, if you wish to use a QStringList you can use join().  Also, QStrings can be combined using the + operator.  Also, [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qstring.html)s can be joined using the .arg() function.

Also, you may be interested in [serialization](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/datastreamformat.html). This will allow you how to write almost any Qt object to a stream.